# Uncaught ReferenceError drawer is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: html, polymer, onclicklistener, custom-element, polymer-2.x

Im pretty new to polymer 2.0 and am trying to get my head around certain errors i dont seem to understand.

One of them being this:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: drawer is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick`

So to explain my problem, I am trying to use **`app-drawer`** which will slide from left to right on a click event. But the click event returns the above error. How can I make sure the drawer is defined? (Btw, I'm following the code snippet that is provided in the main website of `app-layout` section. - https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout).

Here is my code:

```html
<app-header reveals>
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="drawer.toggle()"></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title>My app</div>
    <paper-icon-button icon="delete"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="close"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-progress value="10" indeterminate bottom-item></paper-progress>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
<app-drawer id="drawer" swipe-open></app-drawer>
```

This is exactly the same in the website, so why does it work for them, but not me.

The problem occurs when i click on the menu icon.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you not to use `onclick`..

They are providing really bad approach and the reason why your code isn't working is propably because you are using `shadow` dom, instead, they are using `shady` dom.

It means, you can't simply do `document.getElemenetById("drawer").toggle();` in shadow dom. There are `shadowRoots` which wrap whole element into some block that is not accessible from outside. (unless you use `shadowRoot` notation.)

nevermind, to make it work, you have to do some boilerplate function.

First, use `on-tap` instead of `onclick`. This is just Polymer function.  Your `paper-icon-button` will be like:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="openDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
```

and then, define function `openDrawer`:

```
openDrawer: function() {
  this.$.drawer.toggle();
}
```

and that's it. It's also good to mention that if you are using native elements in Polymer 2.0, you should use `on-click` listener. If you want to use `on-tap` you have to extend `Polymer.GestureEventListeners`.

```
class somElement extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element){}
```

Comment: Thank you Kuba mate! It really make sense now. It boils down to shadow vs shady then.. +1 for the clear explanation. Really appreciate it. ;)

Comment: Great explanation! @kuba